# How to increase height of view by value in SnapKit?

Tags: ios, swift, snapkit

I want to increase height by 100 in SnapKit, but I don't know how to do it. It suppose to be something like this, but it's not working

```
mainView.snp.makeConstraints { make in
    make.center.equalToSuperview()
    make.height.equalTo(otherView.snp.height + 100) // problem here
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `inset` or `offset`:

```swift
make.height.equalTo(otherView.snp.height).offset(100)
```